# Why does sed provide an "invalid content" error on linux but not on mac

Tags: regex, linux, bash, macos, sed

I have the following `sed` extended regular expressions replacement inside a `bash` script:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's~^[[:blank:]]*\\iftoggle{[[:alnum:]_]+}{\\input{([[:alnum:]_\/]+)}}{}~\\input{\1}~' file.txt
```

which should replace strings like

```
\iftoggle{xx_yy}{\input{xx_yy/zz}}{}
```

with

```
\input{xx_yy/zz}
```

inside `file.txt`.

This works just fine locally, on `OS X`, but the script needs to be POSIX. Specifically, it fails on my remote `Travis CI` build (which uses `Linux`). While `sed -E` is not documented for `GNU sed`, it behaves just like `sed -r` and seems to work fine, allowing for a POSIX version of sed with extended regular expressions.

The error given is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 81: Invalid content of \{\}
```

I'm also not sure where the error starts counting characters from, whether it's the beginning of the line, or only that part which is encased in quotes (the expression)?

Comment: in ERE, `{}` are used to specify quantifiers like `{5}` to match preceding character 5 times.. so they have to escaped to match literal `{}`... so I doubt how it is working on osx... `echo '\iftoggle{xx_yy}{\input{xx_yy/zz}}{}' | sed -E 's~^[[:blank:]]*\\iftoggle\{[[:alnum:]_]+\}\{\\input\{([[:alnum:]_\/]+)\}\}\{\}~\\input{\1}~'`

Comment: since there are too many `{}` to be escaped, you would be better off using BRE... `echo '\iftoggle{xx_yy}{\input{xx_yy/zz}}{}' | sed 's~^[[:blank:]]*\\iftoggle{[[:alnum:]_]\+}{\\input{\([[:alnum:]_\/]\+\)}}{}~\\input{\1}~'`

Comment: @Sundeep I'm getting an `RE error: invalid character class` on both of your suggestions on osx.

Comment: try a simpler example on both: `echo '{sample}' | sed 's/{/#/'` ... I don't have osx, so I don't know if osx sed has any specific behavior... what is the sed version on osx?

Comment: The simple example works just fine. osx uses a BSD version of sed. Perhaps this is helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed

Comment: @ScottWilton: Do you appreciate a `perl` version of this `sed`, which can make things complex and more portable?

Comment: @Inian I'm not sure one implements that in a bash script. But potentially, yes.

Comment: @ScottWilton: It is not a a full-fledged perl script, but just a command-line thing, calling the `perl` interpreter, you can run similar to `sed`, and moreover do the lines start with multiple blanks in your input file? Can you confirm just that

Comment: @Inian I can write my input file such that it will never have blanks at the start of the line. That's not an issue if it makes a difference.

Comment: @ScottWilton: Sundeep's first suggestion works if you remove the invalid chars. The `invalid character class` error was triggered because of invisible chars within the `[:alnum:]` class. Try this: `echo '\iftoggle{xx_yy}{\input{xx_yy/zz}}{}' | sed -E 's~^[[:blank:]]*\\iftoggle\{[[:alnum:]_]+\}\{\\input\{([[:alnum:]_\/]+)\}\}\{\}~\\input{\1}~'`

Comment: @hansaplast I don't know how they got added... perhaps because it is too long? when I copy paste your suggestion in vim, the invisible chars are present too

Comment: screw that, SO keeps adding those characters, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/7ee6a448cfde802d924f78065b9b8283) to copy/paste

Comment: If this is a TeX file, why don't you use TeX directly? `\def\iftoggle#1#2#3{#2}`. It will be much more robust than using silly regex-based replacements.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Because I'm going to apply another script to my TeX file that understands `\input` but doesn't know how to handle `\iftoggle` since that's provided in an additional package.

Comment: @ScottWilton: that's why I suggested `\def\iftoggle#1#2#3{#2}` that actually _defines_ `\iftoggle` to work as you expect.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm not sure that does what I want. The first step of the third-party script is to "flatten" the TeX file, pulling in the contents from `\input`, then it continues. I'm not sure if the script actually does any TeX parsing or simply replaces the input with the contents of the file.

Comment: @ScottWilton: ah, ok, I get it. If you're using a script that doesn't handle TeX's (insane) syntax properly (i.e., something based on regex or other bad grammar), then you're screwed and you have to pray that what you're doing is never going to break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need ERE here. Using BRE:

```
sed i.bak 's~^[[:blank:]]*\\iftoggle{[[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*}{\\input{\([[:alnum:]_\/][[:alnum:]_\/]*\)}}{}~\\input{\1}~' file.txt
```

`{` don't need to be escaped here but `(` do.

As `+` is not part of the BRE, you can replace `[[:alnum:]_]+` with `[[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*` or with `[[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}`.

And as a side note, `\+` can be used with GNU sed in BRE but keep in mind that it's not portable, it's a GNU extension.

Comment: Is there a reason that you replaced  `[[:alnum:]_]+` with `[[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*`?

Comment: Yes, it's because `+` is not part of BRE. `[[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*` is equivalent to `[[:alnum:]_]+`.

Comment: So in my original version above (in my question), the only thing ERE was doing for me was the `+` and escaping `(`?

Comment: Yes, just that.

Comment: @SLePort: `++` for a more authoritative answer in `sed`

Answer (score 1):

> This does not *directly* answer the question with `sed`, but provides an alternate simpler way to do this in `perl` command-line regex search and replacement.

```
perl -p -e 's|\iftoggle\{(\w+)\}\{\\input\{(\w+)/(\w+)\}\}\{\}|\input\{\2/\3\}|g' file
\input{xx_yy/zz}
```

Using the word-separator as `|` and `\w+` to match the `[[:alnum:]]` characters.

For in-place replacement, use the `-i` flag similar to `sed`

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's|\iftoggle\{(\w+)\}\{\\input\{(\w+)/(\w+)\}\}\{\}|\input\{\2/\3\}|g' file
```

Regarding [`Word-characters(\w)` in `perl POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) character classes page,

> Word characters
>
> A \w matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic character, or a decimal digit); or a connecting punctuation character, such as an underscore ("_"); or a "mark" character (like some sort of accent) that attaches to one of those. It does not match a whole word. To match a whole word, use \w+ . This isn't the same thing as matching an English word, but in the ASCII range it is the same as a string of Perl-identifier characters.

For an input-with multiple folders inside `input`, e.g.

```
cat file
\iftoggle{xx_yy}{\input{xx_yy/zz_yy_zz_kk/dude_hjgk}}{}

perl -p -e 's|\iftoggle\{(\w+)\}\{\\input\{(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)\}\}\{\}|\input\{\2/\3/\4\}|g' file
\input{xx_yy/zz_yy_zz_kk/dude_hjgk}
```

Just plug and play as many as capturing groups you want.

Comment: Does `\w+` include matching underscores? Also, can you provide an example if the path inside `\input` is longer (i.e. contains more than one `/`).

Comment: @ScottWilton: Refer my updated example & more about `\w+`

Comment: So it looks like there's not one easy solution that matches both shorter and longer paths inside 'input'.

Comment: @ScottWilton: Am not sure I got you right? Are you looking for a way to capture the entire path inside `input` in a single capturing group?

Comment: Yes. (filler filler)

Comment: @SLePort's answer is more direct to the question I asked, but I appreciate the perl solution too.

Comment: @ScottWilton: Glad you found it useful, I will try and update a single capture group syntax